# How to show username from a relationship table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and tournaments. I have defined the relationships in the model for both as many to many. I have a third pivot table where user registered to tournament are stored. In this table i want to store the username of the user as well. Here is my storing function

```
$tournament->users()->syncWithoutDetaching([auth()->id()]);
$request->session()->flash('success', 'You have joined the tournament');
return back()->with('tournament', $tournament);
```

What can i add so i can store the username aswell?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Store username where? To pivot table?

Comment: Yes exactly @Spagheeti

Comment: You can try declaring this array: ```$users = [], $users[auth()->id()] = ['username'=>'yourvalue'];``` and then  ```$tournament->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($users);```

Comment: My value would be the username atached with the id , thats what im trying to achive

Comment: So you need to have something like user_1 user_2

Comment: @NipunTharuksha  if he wanted to save it like you said how will it perform with relationships?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Yes for example i want to show the username associated with the id like: users_id = 1 has the value jhon for the username

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj I  already answered ;)

Comment: @JEJ yeah i saw but i want the value to be what is in the users table. I want to fetch it automatically like i get the id

Comment: please see the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Store User name In pivot table just create an extra column named `user_name` in pivot table and you can save it like below

```
 $userId = auth()->id();
 $userName =auth()->user()->name;

 $tournament->users()
            ->syncWithoutDetaching([$userId=>['user_name'=>$userName]]);
$request->session()->flash('success', 'You have joined the tournament');
return back()->with('tournament', $tournament);
```

To Fetch username as well when calling the relation add `withPivot()` to your Model

```
public function relationName(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class)->withPivot('user_name');
}
```

**Update**

```
 $userName =  auth()->user()->name ; // Instead name get the value you want from table column name
```

[check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-auth)

Comment: Thank you for the answer appreciate it. But here $userName = "john"; is there a way that to not declare it manually but the value to be that associated with the id

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj its just an example :) you can use any values bro.. like if you want username is from `users` table use `$userName =User::where('id', auth()->id())->first('username')`

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj You can replace first two line of the JEJ answer with the following lines

```$user = auth()->user();
$userId = $user->id;
$userName = $user->name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for being an hard time :) @JEJ

Comment: Actually @JEJ was right. But your question was bit unclear. By the way its happy to help you.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha yeah my bad, english isnt my first language so its a bit hard for me :)

Comment: No issue . We all have that issue.